# f is a real valued uniformly continuous function defined over a bounded subset A of R. Prove that the range of f is bounded in R.

Tags: real-analysis

If A is closed, it is compact. Therefore the range is compact. Since the range is contained in R, it is bounded.
Assume A is not closed and f is unbounded over A. Therefore there exists a sequence a(n) in A such that  f(a(n)) tends to infinity(or negative infinity). I assume the case f(a(n)) tends to infinity.
a(n) has a convergent subsequence b(n) with limit b. f(b(n)) tends to infinity. Therefore b does not belong to A. Since f(b(n)) will tend to f(b) if b belongs to A. 
I am not able to proceed beyond this point. I am looking for an explaination which uses the sequential criteria for uniformly continuous functions.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, it maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.  Therefore we can extend $f$ to a continuous map on the closure of $A$, which is a compact set, and its image under this extension is also compact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

They don't ask you to show that the range is closed but bounded ! Moreover, $A$ is only bounded, not closed ! Let $x\in \overline{A}\backslash A$. Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset A$ a sequence that converge to $x$. Since it's uniformly continuous, $(f(a_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence (why ?). With this information, you can now prove that you can prolonge $f$ by continuity on $\overline{A}$. Let call $g:\overline{A}\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ the continuous function s.t. $g|_A=f$. Now, indeed, $\overline{A}$ is compact. Then, you can easely show by contradiction that $g(\overline{A})$ is bounded (it's in fact compact, but it's not the question). Since $f(A)\subset g(\overline{A})$, you can finally conclude that $f(A)$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the help.The question mentions that A is bounded.I just needed to assume 2 cases, A being closed and not being closed. When I talked about A being closed, i was assuming one of the cases. I have also mentioned in my explaination that I have assumed the case where A is not closed. That is where I got stuck. In the case where I assumed A is closed, I used that fact that its image under f is compact. Since f(A) is compact in R, it is bounded. I was not using compactness of f(A) to show f(A) is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can choose $\delta\gt0$ so that
$$x,y\in A,\ |x-y|\le\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\le1.$$
Partition $A$ into finitely many sets of diameter at most $\delta,$ i.e.,
$$A=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\text{ where }x,y\in A_i\implies|x-y|\le\delta.$$
Then for each $i$ the set $f(A_i)$ is bounded, in fact has diameter at most $1,$ and the set
$$f(A)=\bigcup_{i=1}^nf(A_i)$$
is the union of a finite number of bounded sets, so it too is bounded.

The same proof works in any finite-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n.$ In a general metric space, the assumption "$A$ is bounded" would have to be strengthened to "$A$ is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#Definition_for_a_metric_space)." By the way, the conclusion can also be strengthened to "$f(A)$ is totally bounded"; for that just replace $|f(x)-f(y)|\le1$ with $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\varepsilon.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understant it now.